# Extract value from string using regex that has a pattern

Tags: java, regex

Want to return a extracted value from string which matches a particular pattern.
Fot eg: i want to extract "hotmail" from String s = "abc@hotmail.com"

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class regexprac{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String x = "xyz@hotmail.com";
        String existingdomain = "hotmail";

        Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+ "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");

        if(existingdomain.equals(emailPattern.matcher(x))){
            System.out.println("Found it");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not found it");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This is not getting the answer. I want the emailPattern to extract hotmail form the email

Comment: Have you tried to get the text after the `"@"`?

Comment: is it always going to be hotmail?

Comment: No its not going to be hotmail every time

Comment: I need to extract stuff between @ and first "." after "@"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(existingdomain.equals(emailPattern.matcher(x))){
```

You are comparing `Matcher` object with string. That's never going to evaluate to true. See [`Pattern.matcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

You need to invoke the `find()` and `group()` methods on the matcher and compare the return value with your string.

---

**Update**

```
String x = "xyz@hotmail.com";
String y = "xyz@outlook.com";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@([^.]+)\\.");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("found: " + m.group(1));
}
m = p.matcher(y);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("found: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
found: hotmail
found: outlook
```

Comment: find() method returns the value??

Comment: Moreover I want stuff between "@" and first "." encountered after @

Comment: @user3229011 `String` class has some methods that may help you: [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) and [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-).

Comment: I want to use regex for it..and not substring and indexOf

Comment: @user3229011: Check the update. Is that close to what you are looking for?

Comment: @user3229011 I don't understand why you want to complicate this problem so much, if saying *it is for learning purposes* you won't learn something really valuable. Divide the problem into two steps: validate the email using a regex, then after validating it, obtain the desired substring from the email. The most simple you keep the solution, the most value you can generate.

Comment: what does ([^.]+) mean??

Comment: That means group of one or more characters, any characters except `.`. And that group should be preceded by a `@` and followed by a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class regexprac{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String x = "xyz@hotmail.com";
        String existingdomain = "hotmail";

        Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("(^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+)(@)([A-Z0-9.-]+)(\\.)([A-Z]{2,6}$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = emailPattern.matcher(x);
        if(matcher.find())){
            System.out.println("Found it");
            String provider = matcher.group(2);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not found it");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the pattern between @ and first "." to be extracted

Comment: but how can we group it to extract the value I desire